# No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0-alpha05 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute ‘org.gradle.plugin. with value 7.5-rc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgVvS.png)

Answer (score 15):

this work for me

1. go to Setting
2. wrote Gradle in the search bar
3. change gradle JDK

[image]

> Update - another problem

if you can't find Gradle in Settings

- do these steps

[image]

1. File ==> Project Structure
2. SDK Location ==> Gradle Settings
3. change Gradle JDK
4. File ==> Project with Grad

Answer (score 3):

change Java version in setings
from your to 11th